# importing local installation of PySide into Python

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Have been searching for this for a while and trying different solutions, but nothing seems to fix my problem.

I am sitting on a unix server, and have installed PySide locally in my home directory, so python will not pick it up. (not added to PYTHONPATH?).

I am not able to import PySide in my python script. 
Trying the following:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('~/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.5-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/')

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
```

Not sure if I am appending the correct path. At least there is a `init.py` file there and `QtCore.so`, and other `*.so` files.
Is it still correct to `import from PySide`?

Comment: Have you tried appending `~/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.5-64bit-release/pyside/` to `sys.path`? Usually the paths you append should contain the folder name (module name) which in turn contains the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I think the sys.path.append line does this. I try to print sys.path, and the path is listed. 
~/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.5-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/' contains QtCore. From there, the c++ code for Qt is located in:
QtCore/PySide/QtCore
Not sure what level I need to import. Trying out some different combinations, and not sure how to correctly write my import statement.

Comment: is there reason why you are not using virtualenv ?

Comment: Python doesn't automatically expand `~` or `$HOME` in paths appended to `sys.path`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. As @ekhumoro said, python does not expand `~`. So fixed the path and I also noticed that I was one level to deep before.
so my path ended up like this:
`/<my home path>/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.5-64bit-release/pyside/`